# Ordering by a Field that's a combination/function of two other fields in NHibernate/LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate

Suppose I had the following...

```
public class User
{
    public virtual string FirstName {get; set;}
    public virtual string LastName {get; set;}

    public virtual string LastNameFirst 
    get
    {
         return LastName.Trim() + ", " + FirstName.Trim();
    }

    protected set
    {
         /*Left empty...*/
    }
}
```

In my UserMap.cs class, I have the following...

```
Map(x => x.FirstName).Column("FirstName").Not.Nullable().Length(255);
Map(x => x.LastName).Column("LastName").Not.Nullable().Length(255);
```

Is it possible to somehow configure it so I can call...

```
var orderedUsers = users.OrderBy(i => i.LastNameFirst).ToList()
```

I got "could not resolve property: LastNameFirst" when I tried this.

Comment: can you try `users.OrderBy(i => i.LastName.Trim() + ", " + i.FirstName.Trim())` ??

Answer (score 2):

Either use [Juan Carlos proposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37264356/ordering-by-a-field-thats-a-combination-function-of-two-other-fields-in-nhibern#comment62055712_37264356) :

> ```
> var orderedUsers = users.OrderBy(
>     i => i.LastName.Trim() + ", " + i.FirstName.Trim()).ToList();
> ```

Or chain ordering, which, depending on your data, may be suitable to your needs, though it may differ from ordering on your string concatenation/trimming:

```
 var orderedUsers = users.OrderBy(
     i => i.LastName.Trim()).ThenBy(i => i.FirstName.Trim()).ToList();
```

Otherwise, map your `LastNameFirst` as a SQL formula (hbm example, I am not using Fluent or map-by-code but I know formula are available with them too; assuming SQL-Server, adapt syntax if it is something else):

```
<property name="LastNameFirst"
  formula="ltrim(rtrim(LastName)) + N', ' + ltrim(rtrim(FirstName))" />
```

Then you can order by it with [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate):

```
var orderedUsers = users.OrderBy(i => i.LastNameFirst).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

if users is IQueryable

Try this

var orderedUsers = users.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(i => i.LastNameFirst).ToList();

or

var orderedUsers = users.ToList().OrderBy(i => i.LastNameFirst);

Comment: Wow... that worked. Can you explain the logic of how that worked or what it's doing? Is it building an in-memory list or something? My only concern is that there are a lot of records, so I'm doing some pagination and filtering -- I want this to be done from the Database/SQL.

Comment: Yes, this is in memory. It is not actually usable for replacing an ordering on a query supposed to happen db side. This will cause issues in case of lots of data, paging db side, ...

Comment: This is not the optimal solution because when you are working with large tables, this solution load all row from the table and process the sort in c# code.